# Regarding Auth0 Validation

Tags: flutter, dart

I dont Know How to Explain This

I have Custom Backend for My Flutter Appliation. Have Implemented Auth0 for my Flutter Application So i can Gain Access to Auth0 Token
My Question is I need to Check my AccessToken to the Custom Backend if the Validation Gets True After that I need to Fetch Data From Custom Backend

The Access Token is on Front End Flutter and the Validation in Backend Typescript

I dont Know How to Check This and How to sent the AccessToken to the Backend this like Crud Operation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the access token in the header of your API call and then at the backend, you could validate the token and if the token is valid then perform operation and send response.

Comment: Header of the Api ? On Flutter